# SQL stored procedure return single record per ID with Max Date for that ID

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, greatest-n-per-group

I am having a problem figuring out how to get a particular result from my data and I can't seem to write a query that will do the trick.

Here is what I have. I have a table [Products] which contains the details of a particular product and I have a second table [ProdTrans]  the two are in a one to many relationship on the Product ID number field "PrID" the ProdTrans table also has a date field for each record of when it was created and a price.
the issue I am having is that I want to build a query that will take the most recent record for each PrID and return them as a list. I tried using a where clause Where Max(Date) but that seems to be only returning records with the most recent date overall and skipping some of the PrID's whose most recent record is not the most recent overall date.

I am uncertain how I should adjust my criteria to correct this issue.

here is what I have written thus far.

```
    Select *
    From ProdTrans
    Where transDate = Max(transDate)
    Order By PrID
```

I want it to basically return a list of all my PrID's on the table with the most recent transaction for the PrID in this case what the current pricing for the product is.

please help I know I am missing something simple but for the life of me can not remember what it is.

**[UPDATE]**

Alright so let me help clarify what I need to have as my output so below I will give an example dataset from the table

PrID     CreateDate     Cost     Margin
001      1/1/2000      25.00     2.10
005      2/11/2005     15.48     1.50
002      3/5/2005      8.49      0.23
001      2/10/2006     22.95     1.19

and so on What I need to get is a list that returns only one instance of each PrID which must be the one with the most recent Date/Time value.
also with some digging I found out that there is no foreign key relationship on the PrID field they are all manually entered (again this is a legacy system that I am trying to patch so I did not set it up nor design it. just have to work around its odd design)
This procedure is being used to output this data set to an external application.

Comment: my answer is correct, i had a bad join

Comment: what about if there is no join? I did some digging in the source material and found that there is not relational connection (don't know why) so the ProdTrans is a stand alone table

Comment: my answer JOIN's to a derived table, there is no real FK required.  My only assumption is that the PRID groups the records in the PRODTRANS tble.  I will update my answer.

Comment: yeah I saw that after looking at it, I am testing right now to check for desired results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT P.PRID, COST,MARGIN
FROM ProdTrans AS P
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(TRANSDATE) AS MAXDATE, PRID
FROM ProdTrans
GROUP BY PRID ) AS M
  ON M.PRID = P.PRID 
 AND M.MAXDATE = P.TRANSDATE
ORDER BY P.PRID
```

Comment: Thanks I will try testing this and see if it gets me what I need

Comment: This will actually return every row of the table (assuming that `PRID` is not null)

Comment: i added the date to the SELECT

Comment: This will **still** return every row of the table, not the cases with the max date

Comment: try my original post.

Comment: What?, no, what you had was only missing one join condition. You had `ON M.PRID = P.PRID`, and it needed to be `ON M.PRID = P.PRID AND P.TRANSDATE = m.MAXDATE`

Comment: ok, i i will fix, thanks..  I am rushing through these today...  i thought he only wanted the id.

Comment: My testing came up with another issue which is that there are other fields in the table and the group by is failing because these fields are not identical so I get
Column 'Margin' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: why don't you post your entire list of required output.  What DB are you using?

Comment: its part of an existing legacy system I will update the initial post

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select * from ProdTrans 
     where
     (prid,date) IN (Select prid,max(date)
                   From ProdTrans
                   group by prid)
```

for Oracle and MySQL DB

Comment: Thanks I will try testing this and see if it gets me what I need

Comment: @TMcKeown it possible and please see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72132/146 fiddle to confirm

Comment: it's not possible in SQL SERVER, the poster never said what DBMS.

Comment: m sure about oracle and mysql not sure about SQL SERVER

Comment: i was going to remove my down vote... why don't you add `For Oracle` to your answer and I can remove my down vote.

Comment: You can indeed use *tuple comparison* to compare multiple columns. But you can't use `=` unless the subquery is guaranteed to return a single row.

Comment: @BillKarwin thanks for pointing out the mistake i have updated the answer i should use IN instead of =